# Centering jQuery Modal Dialog Popup

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Im trying to show a modal dialog/popup when users visit my homepage.

I am able to show the dialog, however it does not appear in the center of the screen.

I am importing these files, in case that is the issue:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { 
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({ 
    width: 'auto',
    // position: 'center',
    center: true, 
    modal: true, 
    autoOption: true, 
    resizable: false 
    }); 
}); 
</script>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Offer" style="text-align:center"><img alt="" src="Pack.jpg"/> </div>
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szEpb/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommenting the `// position: 'center',`

or if it does not work try the below code.Hope this is what you meant.. :)

```
$('body').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
```

If you need to center in at a particular selector try

```
$('your_selector').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
```

Comment: thanks. Where would the above go? Within  $("#dialog-modal").dialog({ ??

Comment: Try writing it outside the $("#dialog-modal").dialog({ });